# User rights assignment in Group Policy Object using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Not able to grant user rights assignment in group policy object using PowerShell
Is there any way or command to add user?

Manual steps:

1. Open Group Policy Management
2. Navigate to the following path in the Group Policy Object
3. Select Policy
4. Right click & Edit: Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment.
5. Add/remove the necessary users

[Click on image for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MukT2.png)

Tried Set-GPPermission but didn't work it adds user in delegation refer to below image
[Result after using Set-GPPermission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFCXD.png)

Comment: set-gppermission?

Comment: @js2010 also used Set-GPPermission but it give edit, modify, etc rights which are mentioned in delegation tab of policy
Added image in post for your reference